# parseerror while return json from controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

From below code I am getting error of parseerror in error: function (jqXHR, exception)
it always gives me this error while in response text I am getting all data which I need.
please provide me way to solve out this problem and get all the details through the success:function

Here is my Script code

```
function Create() {
var objIntegration = {
    ProductCode: $('#ProductCode').val(),
    environmentType: ($("input[type=radio]:checked").val())
};
alert("Your are select product Code is " + objIntegration.ProductCode + " on Environment Type of " + objIntegration.environmentType);


$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/Create",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    //async: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(objIntegration),
    dataType: "Json",

    success: function (data) {
        alert("Hi from Success.");
        if (data.status == "Success") {
            alert("From Success your choose");
        }
    },

    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        alert("Hi from Error");
    }

});
```

Here is my Controller Code

```
        public ActionResult Create(Integration objIntegration)
    {
        string product = objIntegration.ProductCode;
        string type = objIntegration.environmentType;
        string jsonrequest = string.Empty;
        Uri uri = null;
        string ErrorMsg = string.Empty;
        string ResponseXML = string.Empty;
        string Premium = string.Empty;
        string No = string.Empty;
        string PropNo = string.Empty;
        string ResponseTime = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            string tmp = string.Empty;

            string authenticationKey = GetAuthenticationKey(objIntegration.environmentType);


            XmlDocument InputXML = new XmlDocument();
            InputXML.Load(@"D:\Int Kit\4102\4102.xml");

            string xmlcontents = InputXML.InnerXml;
            string inputxml = xmlcontents.ToString();
            string Code = objIntegration.Code;
            if (objIntegration.environmentType == "AAA")
            {
                jsonrequest = @"{

                            ""Input"":
                                        {

                                                     ""UserID"": ""AAA"",
                                                     ""Password"": ""password@1"",
                                                     ""UserRole"": ""ADMIN"",
                                                     ""Code"": ""1"",
                                                     ""ModeOfOperation"": ""NEW"",
                                                     ""AuthenticateKey"": ""0"",
                                                     ""InputXML"": ""1"",
                                                     ""GenerationMode"":""1""
                                        }
                                }";

                uri = new Uri("https://Localhost:........");

            }
            else
            {
                jsonrequest = @"{

                            ""Input"":
                                        {

                                                     ""UserID"": ""test"",
                                                     ""Password"": ""password1"",
                                                     ""UserRole"": ""ADMIN"",
                                                     ""Code"": ""1"",
                                                     ""ModeOfOperation"": ""OLD"",
                                                     ""AuthenticateKey"": ""0"",
                                                     ""InputXML"": ""1"",
                                                     ""GenerationMode"":""1""
                                        }
                                }";



            }


            dynamic rss = JObject.Parse(jsonrequest);
            JObject tempUserData = (JObject)rss.SelectToken("Input");
            tempUserData["AuthenticateKey"] = authenticationKey;
            tempUserData["ProductCode"] = Code;
            tempUserData["InputXML"] = inputxml;

            string data1 = rss.ToString();
            if (uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
                request.KeepAlive = false;
                request.ContentLength = data1.Length;
                request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
                writer.Write(data1);
                writer.Close();


                string startTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                tmp = reader.ReadToEnd();
                string endTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

                DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startTime, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
                DateTime endate = DateTime.ParseExact(endTime, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);

                TimeSpan ts = endate.Subtract(startDate);
                int second = (int)ts.Seconds;
                Response.Write(second.ToString());

                XMLResponse objXMLResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<XMLResponse>(tmp);
                string errorText = objXMLResponse.SaveResult.ErrorText;
                string errorCode = objXMLResponse.SaveResult.ErrorCode;
                string outputXML = objXMLResponse.SaveResult.OutputXML;
                double netPremium = objXMLResponse.SaveResult.NetPremium;
                double serviceTax = objXMLResponse.SaveResult.ServiceTax;
                double totalPremium = objXMLResponse.SaveResult.TotalPremium;
                string proposalNumber = objXMLResponse.SaveResult.ProposalNumber;
                string quotationNumber = objXMLResponse.SaveResult.QuotationNumber;

                ErrorMsg = errorText;
                ResponseXML = outputXML;
                Premium = totalPremium.ToString();
                QuotationNo = quotationNumber;
                ProposalNo = proposalNumber;
                ResponseTime = second.ToString();


            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorMsg = ex.ToString();
        }

        return Json(new
        {
            status = "Success",
            jsproduct = product,
            jstype = type,
            jsQuotationNo = QuotationNo,
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //  return View();
    }
```

[Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO5Qj.jpg)

[xhr.Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhHxO.jpg)
[F12_xhr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErILV.jpg)

Comment: Your code is expecting JSON data to be returned. Are you sure you are getting a JSON string as the response to your ajax call ? Check the response tab of your xhr call in network tab of F12

Comment: @Shyju thanks for reply please see the snapshot of xhr.response and json

Answer (score 0):

[It](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhHxO.jpg) is not valid JSON, the UUID like string `983cbb...86dd18` in front of the curly brace `{` is breaking the JSON. You can also use this tool called [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com) to validate your JSON in the future.

Comment: "983cbb...86dd18" is my I authentication Key. but I don't understand how it comes in responsetext. please guide me if I am doing wrong in my code.